# Can I trigger an event for only one address in Ethereum network?

Tags: events, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3py

I am working on Ethereum smart contract to build a marketplace between sellers and buyers. When someone (y) ask a product from (x), can I trigger an event to let ONLY (x) he has a new request for his product ??

I have done the full code of the smart contract and I have done the event listening as well using web3.py. But what I want is not triggering the event for everyone on the network, only the seller should have a notice, so every seller has his own requests list.

I have no idea if this is possible or not, if yes, could someone please help me what I should update in the event listing code I have

```
def handle_event(event):
    if (event.args['_new_req'] == True ):
        print(' New request for the product ')
    else:
        print (' The request has been failed ')

def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
            handle_event(event)
        time.sleep(poll_interval)
def _new_req_listen():
    block_filter = contract.events._new_req.createFilter(fromBlock = 'latest')

    worker1 = Thread(target=log_loop, args=(block_filter, 2))
    worker1.start()
```

Could I filter the same event to be triggered in different cases or for different persons in the network ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you think of this from the high level (algorithm) point of view, without dropping down to the code immediately.

For your requirement of having an event raised for a particular person (seller), the way to do this would be either:

- One event list. The event data structure contains a "destination" address property. You can set "destination" to a unique value (e.g. 0x000000) than means "everyone", or you can set "destination" to one person (e.g. the address of the seller).
- Or, have an unique event list for every seller. Your event processing will need to have an outer loop to iterate over all the event lists. You can also have a 'global' event list which means every seller is sent the event.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but kindly I don't understand what do you mean by event data structure?? can I really change the destination address and add the seller address? where I can configure this ? could you explain it with an example so I can get the idea better, Many thanks